# Xamarin Android out of order async call

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I'm just getting into Android Development using Xamarin with Visual Studio 2015 Update 3.  I'm trying to create a simple spinner, but something is going very, very wrong with the order of execution in the debugger.

In shared code, I have an options class that contains common values for dropdowns, etc.

```
public interface IOptionsCache : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // is not observable collection on purpose, the entire list is replaced
    // when data is fetched from the server
    IList<string> States {get;}
}
```

Also in shared code, I have a standard base type to implement INotifyPropertyChanged more easily.

```
public abstract class NotifyDtoBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    protected bool SetField<T>(ref T field, T value, IEqualityComparer<T> comparer = null, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        comparer = comparer ?? EqualityComparer<T>.Default;

        if (comparer.Equals(field, value))
        {
            return false;
        }

        field = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then the actual OptionsCache looks like

```
public class OptionsCache : NotifyDtoBase, IOptionsCache
{

    protected IList<string> _states;
    public IList<string> States
    {
        get { return this._states; }
        set { SetField(ref this._states, value); }
    }

    public async Task PopulateCacheAsync()
    {
        // TODO: fetch options from server
        // for now, populate inline
        this.States = new List<string>(){ "MI", "FL", "ME", ... }
    }
}
```

These are working just fine.  So, in my Activity, I new up an options class, and try and populate a drop down, but things go very wrong.

```
[Activity (Label = "Simple App", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    protected IOptionsCache OptionsCache;
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

        // new OptionsCache has no options to start with
        // need to call PopulateCache to get data
        var options = new OptionsCache();

        // When the list is populated, populate the spinners
        options.PropertyChanged += (sender, args) => PopulateSpinners();

        // HERE IS WHERE THINGS TO BAD!
        // As I step thru the code, when I hit this line (pre-execution) and then F10 to step over, it drops into the PopulateSpinners method and this.OptionsCache == null
        this.OptionsCache = options;

        // populate the cache async and let the property changed event
        // populate the spinners
        options.PopulateCacheAsync();
    }

    protected void PopulateSpinners()
    {
        Spinner statesSpinner = FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.StatesSpinner);

        // this.OptionsCache == null
        ArrayAdapter<string> departureAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, global::Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerDropDownItem, this.OptionsCache.States.ToArray());

        statesSpinner.Adapter = departureAdapter;
    }
}
```

It seems like my assignment call to the class variable is being skipped and the next method is being invoked.  Not sure if it has to do with being an async method or what's going on here...

Comment: I don't know exactly what's happening, but this line `options.PropertyChanged += (sender, args) => PopulateSpinners();` indicates the event is firing on this line. It doesn't appear to have anything to do with the async call.

Comment: It does not fire on that line, it's a lambda callback that fires when property changed is raised.  Notice the => for the lambda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the good news is that the code does actually run correctly... when it is actually deployed to the emulator.

It would seem that the latest code does not always deploy to the emulator and you may end up debugging 'old' code.  One way to tell this is happening, is that the debugger will indicate invalid lines as the next statement (eg, it may say that a blank line or a class definition is the next statement, which is obviously not correct).

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/45327/newest-version-of-code-not-always-deployed-when-debugging-from-xamarin-studio